# Combine a Gauge with a spline in same chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to Combine a Gauge with a spline in same chart.
My requirement is to display continuous variation of a live parameter with a spline while the gauge shows the current value.
I tried, but when i add two series in the same chart, nothing is displayed.